# Android Java and PHP HASH HMAC SHA256 different result

Tags: java, php, base64, hmac

I saw some same questions in stack-overflow but it doesn't find answer.

Android Java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

private String hash_hmac(String str, String secret) throws Exception{
    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    byte[] string = str.getBytes();
    String stringInBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(string, Base64.DEFAULT);
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secretKey);
    String hash = Base64.encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(stringInBase64.getBytes()), Base64.DEFAULT);
    return hash;
}

    String str = "1234";
    String key = "1234";

    try {

        Log.d("HMAC:", hash_hmac(str,key));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("HMAC:","stop");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Result:

```
UHWlHiPrOxxncJTagnlvVcln3xKZ1PKaojFeTMDLXws=
```

And in **PHP** code:

```
$str=base64_encode('1234');
$key='1234';
print(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $str, $key,true)));
```

Result:

```
FBp7PnSG4MQNgcFWAjjlkxNdiqivrmNfnRZur1Dko2Q=
```

As you can see, i have different results. What i do wrong?

PS. I edit code, as we say, but it not helped me. Please, explain, why i have different results?

Comment: you used 2 times the base64_encode function in php, while in Java you used it only once.

Comment: Im fix it, but result is different in php and Android Java.

Comment: can you show us the value of `hash_hmac('sha256', $str, $key,true)` in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this! The small parameter: Base64.NO_WRAP when i encode base64 byte to base64 to hmac.
Tha Android Java code is:

```
private String hash_hmac_test(String base_string, String key) throws Exception {

    try {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), mac.getAlgorithm());
        mac.init(secret);

        String base_string_base64 = Base64.encodeToString(base_string.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(base_string_base64.getBytes());
        //android.util.Base64.encodeT
        String retVal = Base64.encodeToString(digest,Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.v(TAG, "String: " + base_string);


        Log.v(TAG, "String in Base64: " + base_string_base64);

        Log.v(TAG, "key: " + key);
        Log.v(TAG, "result: " + retVal);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return "ok";
}
```

And in PHP code is:

```
base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', base64_encode($str), $key,true))
```

Both result works fine!
Thank you for all!

Comment: and how to decode it in android?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to solve it:

1. Remove the base_encode in line 1

   $str='eyJoYXNoIjoic29tZVJlcUhhc2hTdHIiLCJhbnN3ZXIiOnRydWV9';
2. Remove the base_encode in print

   print(hash_hmac('sha256', $str, $key,true));

Comment: i try, but it not helped me.

Answer (score 0):

> Difference is in **PHP** `$str` initialized with `base64_encode` but in **JAVA** you didn't **encode** during `hash_mac`

All you need to encode in base64 the `str` in **JAVA** before **hash_mac**

```
private String hash_hmac(String str, String secret) {
        String ss = Base64.encodeToString(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secretKey);
        String hash1 = Base64.encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(ss.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        return hash1;
}
```

> Or just change in **PHP** code to remove `base64` in `str` initialization

`$str='eyJoYXNoIjoic29tZVJlcUhhc2hTdHIiLCJhbnN3ZXIiOnRydWV9';`

Comment: im try, but i have different result in php.
((((

Comment: @YaroslavSnisar Sorry. But it shouldn't be. Because I have tested in PHP and in JAVA side.

Comment: it works fine in Java and PHP. BUT in Android JAVA !! different result!

Comment: Im not sure about that.